# Employee's Hours; Finding number of employees first

Tags: java, file

I've got the code figured out to solve this problem, but I can't figure out how to have the number of employee's first and then display the sorted arrays. Here's the code that I have so far

```
public class Project2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [][] hours = {
  {2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},
  {7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},
  {3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},
  {9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},
  {3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},
  {3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},
  {3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},
  {6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9},
};

for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
  int sum = totalHours(hours, i);
  System.out.println("Employee " + i + ": " + sum);
  }
}

public static int totalHours(int[][] time, int rowIndex) {
  int total = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for (int column = 0; column < time[i].length; column++) {
    total += time[rowIndex][column];
  }
  return total;
  }
}
```

Also I've got to get the input from a certain file, which the contents are unknown.. I input certain number from the book just so I could see what was happening, but how can I call on the file contents as well as get the number of employees from that file.

Comment: each {} is an employee? for example {2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8} is the 1st?

Comment: You're correct, but I don't know the number of employees or their hours. It comes from a file somewhere else. I'm trying to display how many employees are in the file on the first line of output.

Answer (score 1):

To read from a file you're gonna need a Scanner

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

for example :

```
 Scanner sc= new Scanner(new File("path\\to\\ur\\file"));
 //to read numbers of employes
 int number=0;
 while(sc.hasNext()){
   sc.nextLine();
   number++;
 }
```

assuming u have an employe on each line... sc.nextLine() reads a line and
returns it as a String. Parsing the file really depends on it's content.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the hours array, you can call

```
int numberOfEmployees = hours.length;
```

... this returns the number of arrays found within hours[][] (it counts the number of hours[])

This works as long as hours[][] is populated - you mention this information comes from somewhere else, so you are omitting some of your file reading code? If you open the file and have this hours[][] array populated, the above code will work. You'd be able to print the number of employees before the total hours etc.

Comment: I really need help with placing the information from the file into this code. I'm not even sure where to start. Can you help with this?

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("prog2.dat"));
  int number = 0;
  while (sc.hasNext()) {
    sc.nextLine();
    number++;
  } /////////////// I add this at the beginning to call on the file and get the number of employees there were. Now I just need help with making the file go into my existing code to where it displays the same thing as the code above. I just really don't know how to do this